# I am travelling with a renewed passport and my US visa is in my old passport which I forgot in the US. What are my options?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, passport-renewals

I appreciate we need to carry both passports at all times and I have been doing so except, due to a distraction, this time I forgot my old passport at home in the US. I am due to fly back soon, which rules out having my old passport mailed to me.

What are my options to go back into the States?

If it helps, I have scans of all documents with me, including the photograph and visa page from the old passport as well as the I-129s form I'm always supposed to carry.

Comment: Before immigration, you have to convince airline to let you board tge flight.

Comment: Mention your nationality and departure city to help people for more info please.

Comment: I did hear a case where a Canadian was allowed to enter US at the road border crossing with a scan of his visa, but it is an anomaly and not the rule. If you are from a high risk country forget about even being allowed to board the plane.

Comment: @DumbCoder indeed. It's unusual for a Canadian even to *have* a US visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not rule out being reunited with your passport so soon.  Since you are going to fly to the USA anyways, if someone couriers the passport to you it just needs to get the courier's base right next to your starting airport. You will likely need a cab from the terminal to get to said base, in general there's no transit there. Of course, without knowing the exact airport we can't know for sure. In such circumstances 24 hours might be plenty, more often than not what takes time for the courier is to get the package from an airport to a residence. Do not forget to check the courier base opening times, often they are closed on weekends and such.